# Proof of this problem needed

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

27 US states send their two senators to a nationwide conference. Is it possible to arrange the 54 people around a round table so that between two people from any state, there are 9 people from other states?

I just filled in spots on a table I drew and found that the answer is no, but I need to prove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove this with contradiction using mod $54$.

Let's assume that senators $1$ and $11$ are from the same state. Then, $11$ and $21$, $21$ and $31$, etc will **not** be from the same state. This means that $20x+1$ and $20x+11$ are from the same state, but if $x=13$, you will get $261$ and $271$ which $\equiv$ $45$ and $1$ (mod $54$). But $45$ and $1$ are from the same state. Contradiction.

Comment: Is this answer correct can someone tell me

Answer (score 3):

Look at it this way:

The conditions **necessarily** imply cycles of $20,$ e.g.

$A B C D E F G H I J A B C D E F G H I J|K\;(second\;cycle\;starts)$

Since $54$ is not evenly divisible by $20$, it is not possible to arrange in the specified way.